# suppress bindings output from gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

When we execute gcp project add-iam-policy-binding, it returns a very verbose output of current bindings. Sometimes, there could be more than 15-20 bindings.

Is there a way to suppress the output to only success or failure?

I tried to use the `--verbose` flag with value `error`. It did not help.

Command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <gcp_project_id> --member=serviceAccount:<service_account_id> --role <role_name>
```

Output:

```
Updated IAM policy for project [<gcp_project_id>].
bindings:
<all existing bindings>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.